# Google Oauth2 - Get list of tokens

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to debug a problem with Google's Oauth2 system where I'm seeing multiple authorizations to our single server-side account. Does Google provide a way to get a list of authorization tokens / refresh tokens issued to our application? I don't need the actual token values per se, just a list of users and permissions.  I haven't been able to find anything so far in Google's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest checking out the Admin SDK's new features on user tokens.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/tokens

The Directory API allows you to audit access tokens that have been issued to 3rd party applications using the OAuth protocol. Authorized applications are granted access to a limited scope of user data, defined in the access token.

Related Google Apps Developer blog post: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/11/new-security-management-features-for.html

Comment: We're issuing the token, not managing the domain. We don't have the relevant permissions.